# Finding an index numpy python

Tags: python, numpy

Consider a NumPy array of shape (8, 8).

**My Question:** What is the index (x,y) of the 50th element?

**Note:** For counting the elements go row-wise.

*Example, in array A, where `A =  [[1, 5, 9], [3, 0, 2]]`  the 5th element would be '0'.*

Can someone explain how to find the general solution for this and, what would be the solution for this specific problem?

Comment: you might want to accept an answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`unravel_index`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html) to find the coordinates corresponding to the index of the flattened array. Usually `np.arrays` start with index 0, you have to adjust for this.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(64).reshape(8,8)
np.unravel_index(50-1, a.shape)
```

Out:

```
(6, 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

In a NumPy array `a` of shape (r, c) (just like a list of lists), the n-th element is

```
a[(n-1) // c][(n-1) % c],
```

assuming that n starts from 1 as in your example.
It has nothing to do with r. Thus, when r = c = 8 and n = 50, the above formula is exactly

```
a[6][1].
```

Let me show more using your example:

```
from numpy import *

a = array([[1, 5, 9], [3, 0, 2]])
r = len(a)
c = len(a[0])
print(f'(r, c) = ({r}, {c})')
print(f'Shape: {a.shape}')
for n in range(1, r * c + 1):
    print(f'Element {n}: {a[(n-1) // c][(n-1) % c]}')
```

Below is the result:

```
(r, c) = (2, 3)
Shape: (2, 3)
Element 1: 1
Element 2: 5
Element 3: 9
Element 4: 3
Element 5: 0
Element 6: 2
```

Answer (score 1):

`numpy.ndarray.faltten(a)` returns a copy of the array `a` collapsed into one dimension. And please note that the counting starts from 0, therefore, in your example 0 is the 4th element and 1 is the 0th.

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[1, 5, 9], [3, 0, 2]])
fourth_element = np.ndarray.flatten(arr)[4]
```

or

```
fourth_element = arr.flatten()[4]
```

the same for 8x8 matrix.

Answer (score 0):

First need to create a 8*8 order 2d numpy array using np.array and range.Reshape created array as 8*8
In the output you check index of 50th element is [6,1]

```
    import numpy as np
    arr = np.array(range(1,(8*8)+1)).reshape(8,8)
    print(arr[6,1])
```

**output will be 50**

or you can do it in generic way as well by the help of numpy where method.

```
    import numpy as np
    def getElementIndex(array: np.array, element):
        elementIndex = np.where(array==element)
        return f'[{elementIndex[0][0]},{elementIndex[1][0]}]'

    def getXYOrderNumberArray(x:int, y:int):
        return np.array(range(1,(x*y)+1)).reshape(x,y)

    arr = getXYOrderNumberArray(8,8)
    print(getElementIndex(arr,50))
```